# How to get the value of lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm pretty stumped with this one.

I'm developing an HTML Extension method that accepts an `int` value in the form of a lambda expression.

I've tried to emulate it the best I could below in a simple c# application. I'm having trouble calling my extension method in the format of the required lambda expression. This extension method is pigging backing on some Telerik controls, and I'm trying to define some standards among the us of the controls in my department. (I still haven't to figuring out how to the `int` value out either lol).

I've tried to document it and name specific pieces of code the best I could!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new CustomerDatabase<MyCustomers>();
        db.Customers.Add(new MyCustomers { Id = 1, Name = "Gandalf the Grey" });
        db.Customers.Add(new MyCustomers { Id = 2, Name = "Bilbo Baggins" }); 
        //Was watching Fellowship of the Ring while doing this lol

        //This foreach is similar to the foreach that would be 
        //in my MVC view where db.Customers is really my ViewModel
        foreach (var item in db.Customers)
        {
            //This is where my trouble begins... :(
            Helpers.WriteIdToConsole(item, item.Id);
            Helpers.WriteIdToConsole(item => );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CLASS #1
    /// Serves as a holding container for records
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    public class CustomerDatabase<TModel>
        where TModel : class
    {
        public List<TModel> Customers { get;set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CLASS #2
    /// Simple 'model' class in an MVC View
    /// </summary>
    public class MyCustomers
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CLASS #3
    /// Replicates a custom HtmlExtension class I'm developing
    /// </summary>
    public static class Helpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Method #A
        /// One of the methods I'm working on
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="expression"></param>
        public static void WriteIdToConsole<T>(Expression<Func<T, int>> expression)
            where T : class 
        {
            var id = 999;
            Console.WriteLine($"Id: {id}");
        }
    }
}
```

### Update #1

Here is what I have access to in my Razor View. The method `cols.NavigationButton` is my extension method that I'm trying to build. I have to create a new instance of a class of type `Event` or of type `TObj` if keeping with Kirill Shlenskiy's suggested answer below.

```
@model List<Event>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Event>()
      .Name("pagingGrid")
      .Columns(cols =>
      {
          cols.NavigationButton("Edit", "Edit", "Event",new Event(), p => p.Id);
          cols.Bound(p => p.Name);
      })
      .StandardPagingGrid("Event", "Administration")
)
```

Comment: @JenishRabadiya That would mean making the foreach loop as such: `foreach (var item in db.Customers)
            {
                var id = item.Id;
                Helpers.WriteIdToConsole(item => id);
            }`, and this results in compiler errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you say you're still figuring out "how to get the int value out", so I'll assume that you're after a more generic implementation which can give you the name of the member being accessed *and* its value. Here's a snippet for you:

```
public static void WriteToConsole<TObj, TMember>(TObj obj, Expression<Func<TObj, TMember>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpr = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    string memberName = memberExpr.Member.Name;
    Func<TObj, TMember> compiledDelegate = expression.Compile();
    TMember value = compiledDelegate(obj);

    Console.WriteLine($"{memberName}: {value}");
}
```

Usage:

```
var dummy = new Dummy { ID = 123 };

WriteToConsole(dummy, d => d.ID); // Outputs "ID: 123"
```

I have removed the generic reference type constraint (`where T : class`) as this will work fine on value types too.

Key thing to note is that in order to extract the value you need not just the expression capable of doing so, but also an instance to pass to the delegate compiled from the expression (so you were on the right track with the first `Helpers.WriteIdToConsole` call in your code - you just needed to get it to the finish line).

**Edit**

If you only care about extracting basic member information from the expression, you can use a slightly different approach:

```
public static MemberInfo Member<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    // This is a tricky case because of the "object" return type.
    // Providing an expression which has a value return type will
    // result in a UnaryExpression body, whereas an expression which
    // has a reference return type will have a MemberExpression Body.
    UnaryExpression unaryExpr = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
    MemberExpression memberExpr = (MemberExpression)(unaryExpr == null ? expr.Body : unaryExpr.Operand);

    return memberExpr.Member;
}
```

Basic usage:

```
MemberInfo id = Member<MyCustomers>(item => item.Id);

Console.WriteLine(id.Name); // Outputs "Id"
```

The way you would plug it in:

```
public static void NavigationButton<T>(string ..., string ..., string ..., Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    MemberInfo member = Member(expression);

    // Do something with member, cast to PropertyInfo if needed etc.
}

...

NavigationButton<MyCustomers>("Edit", "Edit", "Event", p => p.Id);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to be able to get the value without having to pass an instance of `obj`? Due to the nature of the extension method, I'm not able to actually get a single instance of an `item` in the model. Does that make sense?

Comment: See Update #1 of my original post. Updated with code.

Comment: You cannot get the property *value* without a concrete `item` instance to extract it from. You can, however, extract a `MemberInfo` (or, more specifically, `PropertyInfo`) without an actual object instance. If knowing the property name/type is all you care about, that could be useful. Would that suffice?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I basically am only able to pass the type and property in the following fashion: `item => item.Id`. And inside of the method, I need to be able to get the value of the property that is passed, in this case it is `Id`.

Comment: Truth be told if member name is all you need you can simply use `nameof(MyCustomers.Id)`. If, however, you require more than that, I've got a nifty little utility method you can use to get the `MemberInfo` object from the expression. I'll make an edit in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

You are required to pass Expression to the method and also need to specify the type argument explicitly.

You may use/call that method(`WriteIdToConsole`) like following

```
foreach (var item in db.Customers)
{
    Helpers.WriteIdToConsole<MyCustomers>(myCustomer => myCustomer.Id);
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zSxLyc) is the dot net fiddle for full code review.

Comment: How does `myCustomer.Id` get the value of `item.Id`?

Comment: @JustinAdkins no this is not the value of `item.Id`. Infact you are required to invoke that expression from the method `WriteIdToConsole` Whatever you will pass there while invoking this expression, myCustomer variable would get that. But it is required to be instance of type `MyCustomers` as it defined by your template.

Comment: @Jenish Rabadiya  Helpers.WriteIdToConsole(item, item.Id); is completely different from  Helpers.WriteIdToConsole(MyCustomer, MyCustomer.Id); and that is why @ Justins Adkins asked How does myCustomer.Id get the value of item.Id?